Tkinter - binding individual shapes on a canvas
I have a list of coordinates for rects. I iterate through them to create rectangles on a canvas. I wanna bind every created rectangle to a callback so that I can edit each rectangle individually. Specifically, I want something to happen when I hover over a rectangle.
I know how to use canvas.tag_bind to bind every rect to the same function, but I somehow want to be able to know which rect I am hovering over
Perhaps there is a different method to achieve this, somehow getting the id or a tag of the rect after hovering them?
In short: I want to know which rectangle (that are created dynamically and there can be x of them) I am hovering over
for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
    tag = 'rect_' + str(i)  
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3], width=4, 
    outline='green', tags=('rect', tag)) 
    self.canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<Enter>', lambda e: self.on_rect_hover_enter(e, id=tag))

def on_rect_hover_enter(self, e, id):
    print(id)

The result of this code is that every time I hover over a rect, only the last created rect id is printed
I deduct that a callback can only be bound to one specific rect?

I was able to find a function:
canvas.gettags('current')

'current' gets you the currently hovered item, and you can get its tags with that function
